# Real numbers in Coq

Tags: coq, real-number

In [https://www.cs.umd.edu/~rrand/vqc/Real.html#lab1](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Errand/vqc/Real.html#lab1) one can read:

> Coq's standard library takes a very different approach to the real numbers: An axiomatic approach.

and one can find the following *axiom*:

```
Axiom
  completeness :
    ∀E:R → Prop,
      bound E → (∃x : R, E x) → { m:R | is_lub E m }.
```

The library is not mentioned but in [Why are the real numbers axiomatized in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933107/why-are-the-real-numbers-axiomatized-in-coq) one can find the same description :

> I was wondering whether Coq defined the real numbers as Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts, so I checked Coq.Reals.Raxioms and... none of these two. The real numbers are axiomatized, along with their operations (as Parameters and Axioms). Why is it so?

> Also, the real numbers tightly rely on the notion of subset, since one of their defining properties is that is every upper bounded subset has a least upper bound. The Axiom completeness encodes those subsets as Props."

Nevertheless, whenever I look at https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Raxioms.html I do not see any axiomatic approach, in particular we have the following *lemma*:

```
Lemma completeness :
    forall E:R -> Prop,
      bound E -> (exists x : R, E x) -> { m:R | is_lub E m }.
```

Where can I find such an axiomatic approach of the real numbers in Coq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The description you mention is outdated indeed, because since I asked the question you linked, I rewrote the axioms defining Coq's standard library real numbers in a more standard way. The real numbers are now divided into 2 layers

- constructive real numbers, that are defined in terms of Cauchy sequences and that use no axioms at all;
- classical real numbers, that are a quotient set of constructive reals, and that do use 3 axioms to prove the least upper bound theorem that you mention.

Coq easily gives you the axioms underlying any term by the `Print Assumptions` command:

```
Require Import Raxioms.
Print Assumptions completeness.

Axioms:
ClassicalDedekindReals.sig_not_dec : forall P : Prop, {~ ~ P} + {~ P}
ClassicalDedekindReals.sig_forall_dec
  : forall P : nat -> Prop,
    (forall n : nat, {P n} + {~ P n}) -> {n : nat | ~ P n} + {forall n : nat, P n}
FunctionalExtensionality.functional_extensionality_dep
  : forall (A : Type) (B : A -> Type) (f g : forall x : A, B x),
    (forall x : A, f x = g x) -> f = g
```

As you can see these 3 axioms are purely logical, they do not speak about real numbers at all. They just assume a fragment of classical logic.

If you want an axiomatic definition of the reals in Coq, I provided one for the constructive reals

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Abstract.ConstructiveReals.
```

And this becomes an interface for classical reals if you assume the 3 axioms above.

Answer (score 1):

These descriptions are outdated.  It *used* to be the case that the type `R` of real numbers was axiomatized, along with its basic properties. But nowadays (since [2019](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/10827)?) it is defined in terms of more basic axioms, more or less like one would do in traditional mathematics.